# How to add registration form validation condition on Openedx?

Tags: javascript, django, openedx

I'm working on a project based on open edx. I added a phone_number field to the Userprofile model, so that phone number will be required when users register. The phone number need to be 11 digit.

How do I add constrain on the phone number field of the registration form?

Addition: my boss requires me to add this constrain through javascript, no change to python files. I'm stuck on it. Help needed.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Set the maxlength property on the HTML input to 11 or preferably use this. It would validate its regex. You can put a placeholder as well to help them know the number entry format

```html
<form action="/">
  <input type=“number” name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{11}" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

See also : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: Where should we add that ? In which file ?

Answer (score 1):

front-end validation with Jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#your_form').submit(function(){
    var phone = $("#id_phone_number");

    if (!phone || typeof(phone) == undefined){
         alert("Phone number required");
         return false;
    }else if (phone.length != 11){
         alert("phone number invalid, 11 digits required");
         return false;
    }
    return true;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where should we add that ? In which file ? –

Comment: bellow your jquery call, inside a script tag